# HEPA filter for GE portable air conditioner?

Tags: air-conditioning, air-filter

I have a GE portable air conditioner like the one shown below and am trying to determine whether there exists (OEM or otherwise) a HEPA air filter I can install in/on this device.  I am unable to locate anything from GE's [accessories page](https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/assembly/APCA08NYLWN1?ModelType=ModelType), so perhaps there are some aftermarket solutions someone is aware of?

My rationale to utilize this air conditioner for filtering, as opposed to buying  a separete HEPA filter, is to potentially save on the cost associated with an outright HEPA filter and leverage my existing air conditioner instead.

[image: image credit: https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/assembly/APCA08NYLWN1?ModelType=ModelType]

Comment: you can make a darn effective filter with a box fan (on sale this time of year) and a hepa furnace filter that fits the face. Attach the filter to the fan. The whole thing can be $20-$40usd.

Answer (score 2):

A HEPA filter would be far too restrictive for a portable air conditioner. Use only the filters that are specified for the a/c. If you want to HEPA filter the indoor air, then use a separate device designed to do that.